# Partition it into as few disjoint contiguous increasing subsequences as possible

Tags: code-golf, subsequence, set-partitions

### Specification

This challenge is simple to state: your input is a non-empty array of nonnegative integers, and your task is to partition it into as few substrings as possible, such that each substring is a permutation of a consecutive integer range.
More formally, if the input array is `A`, then the output is minimum number of partition of `A` into `B`(s):

- Each arrays `B` form a partition of `A` into substrings. Inductively, this means that either `B` is the singleton array containing 1 element from `A`, or the elements of `B` is a subsequence of `A`, which when sorted are contiguous like `x,x+1,x+2,..`.
- The number of arrays `B` is minimal.

### Example

Consider the input array `A = [1,2,3,4,3,5]`.
Output is `2`
One possible minimal partitions are `B = [1,2,3],[4,3,5]`. That's the only partition to 2 substrings.

`{4,3,5}` in sorted order is `{3,4,5}` which is contiguous.

### Input

An array of integers `A`.

### Output

A number, indicate the smallest number of parts `A` can be splitted to.

### Winning criteria

Your submissions will be scored in bytes, with less bytes being better.

Comment: This site is for programming contests (i.e., you post programming **challenges** in **questions**), general programming questions are off-topic here.

Comment: (in other words, because the question is a question, it's off-topic. Counter-intuitive)

Comment: Is this a code-golf? Maybe you should clarify and add a [tag:code-golf] tag.

Comment: I have edited your question to suit our standards. I have also added an objective winning criterion, namely [tag:code-golf]. Feel free to edit / rollback if you disagree with the changes I’ve made. Oh, and welcome to PPCG!

Comment: (well, this way you get completely-useless and very-short programs)

Comment: @JonathanAllan "contiguous subsequence" is the same as "substring".

Comment: Is the example answer 2 because the minimal length of any possible `B` is 2 or because there are 2 such minima? Seems to be some conflict between "your task is to partition it into as few contiguous increasing subsequences as possible" vs "we have Q queries updating single value on `A` asking minimum number of type `B`(s) possible"

Comment: This challenge needs more test cases. I'd suggest `[]`, `[3]`, `[1,2]`, `[2,5]`, `[2,6,3]`, `[1,2,11,12,3,4,9,20,22,10,5,6,14,13]`.

Comment: Another test case: `[3,3,3,2,2,2]`

Comment: I VTC as unclear since there seems to still be confusion regarding the specification. The examples do not match up with the literal meaning of the description.

Comment: [OP's question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48472972/6346504) might help for clarification.

Comment: @ovs the question here has probably mutated from its intent. A new, clear question (or even questions) would be better in my opinion.

Comment: @ovs Actually that is also unclear to me.

Comment: @ovs The [pdf](https://expirebox.com/download/d250698abbe222861fe450d7f0ee6297.html) posted in [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164007/discussion-between-optimus-prime-and-admin-xvii) might though.

Comment: link to my question : https://expirebox.com/download/d250698abbe222861fe450d7f0ee6297.html

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh.... The challenge doesn't match with the PDF. In that case just keep the current challenge, because... we don't care about the OP's original problem.

Comment: @user202729 Maybe my previous edit was right :p

Comment: @JonathanAllan Anything remaining that's still unclear?

Comment: @user202729 yeah `1,2,3,4,5` is not a substring of `1,2,3,4,3,5` - if we go by the examples it should be "subsequence" and the word "contiguous" is just misleading; if we go for substrings then the example is wrong. Which one will lead to less answers being incorrect?!

Comment: @JonathanAllan Edited.

Comment: why have you removed the Link to the PDF?

Comment: @OptimusPrime "Challenges should be self-contained, because links may expire, especially **expire**box links."

Comment: @user202729 Kotlin answer returns `3` for `1,2,8,3,4,3,5,7`, a substring version would return `1` whereas a subsequence version would return `3` so probably the latter (unless also buggy).

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 91 bytes

```kotlin
fold(mutableListOf<Int>()){r,i->r.indexOfFirst{it<i}.let{if(it<0)r+=i else r[it]=i
r}}.size
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
fold(mutableListOf<Int>()) {r,i->
    r.indexOfFirst { it<i }.let {
        if (it<0) r+=i else r[it]=i
        r
    }
}.size
```

### Test

```kotlin
fun MutableList<Int>.f() =
fold(mutableListOf<Int>()){r,i->r.indexOfFirst{it<i}.let{if(it<0)r+=i else r[it]=i
r}}.size

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val i = mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,3,5)
    println(i.f())
}
```

### TIO

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##VY7NCsIwEITvfYo9JliLvxdpC14EQenBo3iImJTFNJXNVtTSZ6+xHsSBhRm+XXauNVt0fWQaB/uG1dnqHXpOt47zxAgJWW9qexHVjxVmoELKlmIc55Sgu+hHYTZInlvkFLvE6uCMCGEiaZQhaOs10BH5lGFEXZd4fOnv30qhE4pKv4I1kXqmByZ0ZS6hjSDoriwgZPDXQUzjWTyPF2GWcli7hSO2TuCnt4y6/g0)

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 82 bytes

```
f=(a,n=Math.min(...a),i=a.indexOf(n))=>1/a[0]?i<0?1+f(a):f(a,a.splice(i,1)[0]+1):1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 139 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
l=length
q(x:r)=map([x]:)(q r)++[(x:y):v|(y:v)<-q r]
q[]=[[]]
s(x:y)=x+l y==last(x:y)
f x=minimum[l y|y<-q x,all(s.sort)y]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Œ!Iċ€1ṀạL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJEXPI92PmtYYPtzZ8HDXQp////9HG@ooGOkoGOsomIBJ01gA)

#### How it works

```
Œ!Iċ€1ṀạL  Main link. Argument: A (array)

Œ!         Take all permutations of A.
  I        Increments; compute the forward differences of each permutation.
   ċ€1     Count the number of 1's i each array of deltas.
      Ṁ    Take the maximum.
        L  Compute the length of A.
       ạ   Take the absolute value of the difference of the maximum and the length.
```

Comment: I believe `[1,2,8,3,4,3,5,7]` should actually not return either 3 or 2 but 1 since there is only a single minimal length partition, `[[1,2],[8],[3],[4,3,5],[7]]`, satisfying the criteria. (Either that or 5 since that's the minimal length)

Comment: That may have been what the OP was going for, but the latest revision clearly asks to *indicate the smallest number of parts A can be splitted to*.

Comment: Also, since `[1,2,3,4,5],[3]` appear as part of the worked example, reordering is clearly allowed.

Comment: Ah, hadn't updated since going out....

Comment: It is not; it has been there since revision 1. By contiguous, the OP appears to mean that the partitions consist of consecutive integers,

Comment: Yeah, it was totally unclear then!